# Close the form only after task has been completed

Tags: c#, async-await, task

I have a cleanup task that deletes a big file on exit.

```
private async Task DoCleanup()
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        File.Delete(FilePath);
    });
}
```

Now I want to await that task on exit (FormClosing event), but the form closes before the file was entirely deleted.

I've tried to cancel the event and exit the application manually, like this:

```
private async void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
   this.Hide();
   e.Cancel = true;
   await DoCleanup();
   Application.Exit();
}
```

But the Task is called over and over again (like an infinite loop). What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make an event that calls a function and bind the event to `Application.Close()` when the `Task` completes.

```
         public async static Task Main(string[] args)
            {

YourClassName classInstance = new YourClassName();

                // Bind the event to something
                classInstance .CompletedTaskEvent += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine("Completed work");

                // Start the work
                await classInstance.DoCleanup();

                Console.ReadLine();
            }


    public class YourClassName
    {
            // Some event
            public event EventHandler CompletedTaskEvent;


            public async Task DoCleanup()
            {
                await Task.Run(async () =>
                {
                    await Task.Delay(2500);

                    // When the task completes invoke the event
                    // And pass the current class instance to the sender
                    // And you can add any kind of event argument you want
                    // however I recommend you make the event generic and then pass the argument type
                    CompletedTaskEvent?.Invoke(this, eventArguments);
                });
            }
    }
```